# Swift: array of objects search

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to search in array of objects in swift
but I didn't know how :(

I tried

```
filteredArrayUsingPredicate
```

but still don't work ,It's giving me an error msg

-- Update --

the error message is

```
swift:42:9: 'Array<search_options>' does not have a member named 'filteredArrayUsingPredicate'
```

-- Update --

```
class search_options {
        let id:String
        let option:String

        init(){}

        init(id:String ,option:String){
            self.id = id
            self.option = option
        }
    }
```

I only want to search in option variable

And when I tried to used

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!)
{
    let filteredArray = filter(search_options_array) { $0 == "test" }
    println(searchBar.text)
}
```

I got this message

```
swift:40:58: 'search_options' is not a subtype of 'String'
```

Comment: What error message? [ask]

Comment: sorry I'm new here and english is not my primary language so I didn't know and it's hard for me to give lots if details but I will try

Comment: I assume you're getting this error because `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is an `NSArray` member. In Swift, you must be using the type `Array` which doesn't have that. Check out @fluidsonic's answer below to find out how to filter an `Array` using the new `filter` method.

Comment: thanks , I tried and I got new error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after long search **I did't !** ,
I was looking to find a way to do a dynamic search like if array of String contains

```
"hello","lo","yes"
```

and I want to get all the strings that contains for example "lo"
I want to get "hello" and "lo"

so the best way I found is regular expression search

so I do a For Loop throw all options in Array and compare every single object variable to the pattern ,and save it in new array on objects

```
    for var i = 0; i < search_options_array.count; i++ {
        let myRegex = "searched_text"
        if let match = search_options_array[i].option.rangeOfString(myRegex, options: .RegularExpressionSearch){
            filtered_options_array.append(search_options(id:search_options_array[i].id,option:search_options_array[i].option) )
        }
    }
```

The best part here you can use all benefits of regular expression and have a copy of yours old array so if you need it.

Thanks every one for helping.

Answer (score 11):

Find index of specific object:

```
if let index = find(myArray, objectIAmLookingFor) {
    // found! do something
}
```

Filter array:

```
let filteredArray = filter(myArray) { $0 == objectIAmLookingFor }
```

Comment: I get this error swift:40:24: Type 'search_options' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Comment: If you want two instances of `search_options` to be comparable using `==` then the class (or struct) has to implement `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: OK I will search to how implement Equatable class ,Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2):

Because `filter` accepts as a predicate a function which maps each element of the given `Array` to a `Bool` value (to determine which value should be filtered out), in your case it may be this way;

```
let a = [
    search_options(id: "a", option: "X"),
    search_options(id: "b", option: "Y"),
    search_options(id: "c", option: "X")
]

let b = filter(a) { (e: search_options) in e.option == "X" }
// ==> [search_options(id: "a", option: "X"), search_options(id: "c", option: "X")]
```

Comment: Worked for me like a glove. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!)
{
    let filteredArray = filter(search_options_array) { $0.option == "test" }
    println(searchBar.text)
}
```

or

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked( searchBar: UISearchBar!)
{
    let filteredArray = filter(search_options_array) { $0.id == "test" }
    println(searchBar.text)
}
```

You must retrieve property of searched object by which you perform searching

Comment: How to check for bool?

Comment: @Satyam what you mean?